# How does Spring decide which bean to inject when there is two candidates defined with @Qualifier?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

Suppose that I have two beans defined like this:

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationA {

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("restTemplateA")
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        //setting some restTemplate properties

        return restTemplate;
    }
}
```

---

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationB {

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("restTemplateB")
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        //setting some restTemplate properties

        return restTemplate;
    }
}
```

When I autowire restTemplate without providing @Qualifier, which bean will be injected? How is it decided?

```
@Service
public class someClass {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

}
```

Note:When I test, one of the bean is injected. It didn't lead any exception.

Note2: I know I can use @Qualifier to inject the bean that I want or I can use @Primary to avoid ambiguity. But **I just want to understand why it is valid for Spring.**

Note3: When I changed the method name in class ConfigurationB to restTemplateB, bean defined in ConfigurationA is injected. Again it didnt' lead any exception.

**I tried this in Spring Boot version 1.4.4**

Comment: `@Bean( name = "firstRestTemplateName" )` then when autowiring into your service add `@Qualifier( "firstRestTemplateName" )`

Comment: You can also annotate a bean with `@Primary` to make it the default

Comment: @RobOhRob thx for your comment. I edited the question.

Comment: Did you try to create two beans in the same configuration class?

Comment: It will result in NoSuchBeanDefinitionException . I assume someClass is not autodetected by spring

Comment: @Hatice Yes I tried now. But again there is no exception, error etc. restTemplateA is injected.

Comment: Yeah the error would only happen when you attempt to run the application! Unless you are using Intellij, which actually does let you know right away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Case1:** Same method (bean) names in configuration classes.

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationA {

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("restTemplateA")
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        //setting some restTemplate properties

        return restTemplate;
    }
}

@Configuration
public class ConfigurationB {

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("restTemplateB")
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        //setting some restTemplate properties

        return restTemplate;
    }
}
```

**Result:** restTemplate in ConfigrationB is injected. restTemplate in ConfiguratioA is **overridden** by restTemplate in ConfigurationB as can be found in the logs:

> o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : **Overriding bean definition**
>   for bean 'restTemplate' with a different definition: replacing ...

### **Important Note**: Bean overriding is disabled by default from spring boot version 2.1 (you can check this [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes#bean-overriding))

**Case2:** Changing method name in ConfigurationB to restTemplateB.

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationA {

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("restTemplateA")
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        //setting some restTemplate properties

        return restTemplate;
    }
}

@Configuration
public class ConfigurationB {

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("restTemplateB")
    public RestTemplate restTemplateB() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        //setting some restTemplate properties

        return restTemplate;
    }
}
```

**Result:** Both beans in ConfigurationA an ConfigurationB are created. Bean in ConfigurationA is injected. Because bean name will be used if a by-type autowiring doesn't find a single matching bean. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30360853/10550738) for more information

Answer (score 1):

I think what you will find, is if you run your application, it will log an error like `requried a single bean but 2 were found`.

What you can do however is remove the ambiguity using the @Qualifier where you need it injected and naming your bean definitions, i.e. for your example.

```
@Configuration
public class Configuration {

    @Bean(name="restTemplateA")
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        //setting some restTemplate properties

        return restTemplate;
    }

    @Bean(name="restTemplateB")
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        //setting some restTemplate properties

        return restTemplate;
    }
}
```

Then when you come to injecting and using the templates

```
@Service
public class someClass {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifer("restTemplateA")
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

}
```

However, you can also mark one of the templates as a Primary with `@Primary`, and this bean will then be used in each place you do not qualify your autowired.

```
    @Bean(name="restTemplateA")
    @Primary
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        //setting some restTemplate properties

        return restTemplate;
    }
```

Comment: In your configuration class example you'll have to rename one of the methods otherwise the signature of RestTemplate restTemplate() is the same for both methods.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you cannot have both configuration classes, because you'll get a bean name conflict. To fix this, rename the method name:

```
@Bean
    @Qualifier("restTemplateB")
    public RestTemplate restTemplateB() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        //setting some restTemplate properties

        return restTemplate;
    }
```

This way, two `RestTemplate` will be created with `restTemplate` and `restTemplateB` name respectively, and the first one will be injected in the service class.