# SpringBoot @Autowire why does this example work?

Tags: java, spring-boot, autowired

I have created this class:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

...

@Component("notTheNameTestMe") //shouldnt this only work with testMe ?
public class TestMe {

    public void showMsg() {
        System.out.println("Autowiring works");
    }

}
```

And I'm using it this way in a second class (or better: controller):

```
import com.example.TestMe; //shouldnt this be not necessary with autowire? But getting error else...

...

@Autowired
private TestMe testMe;

...

this.testMe.showMsg();
```

But this works perfectly (so maybe Im not really using autowire here?), it even works if I rename the whole TestMe class to TestMeSomething (if I adjust the import in the second class)
I dont really understand what @Autowired does. I thought it just scans for SpringBoot Components (which are named by the string in @Component() and when it finds a match it Injects the dependancy. But in my example the match is impossible and I still can see the message "Autowiring works" in the console. This shouldnt be like this if I would really use autowire here or? What am I understanding in a wrong way? What is the difference to using new TestMe() then? I have the dependancy already with the import or? So not a real dependancy injection, or?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30360589/does-spring-autowired-inject-beans-by-name-or-by-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring is not operating on the name in the `@Component` annotation.  Rather it's using the name of the class.  It's simply finding a class named `TestMe` because that's the type of the variable you've annotated with @Autowired.